# strange behavior SSL acts when rewriting url

Tags: mod-rewrite, ssl, ssl-certificate

I believe there is something weird when I have rewritten my urls. My website links are forced to use SSL and when I click on any, the browser shows OK for SSL on Chrome (green color on https), safe site or identified certificate on Firefox, and the same OK working SSL on other browsers.

Now the problem starts whenever I rewrite the url using `mod_rewrite` and shorten the link a red sign shows up on Chrome, not identified on FireFox, and the same issue on other browsers.

I guess the problem is somewhere in the rewrite code or something is missing has to be added!

**Update #1**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/pro)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/loop/sps/click/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/loop/sps/click
RewriteRule foo/loop/sps/click/(pro)(/(.*))?$ $1$2 [R,L]
```

and of course adding php handler : `DirectoryIndex index.php`

**Update #2**

The error I get is the red sign in Chrome for example. That happens when I enter a url shortened using rewrite url `mod_rewrite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSL issues can be complex and depend on several different variables. The most likely case is that when you rewrite the URL's, you are changing the host name. Let's say you rewrite "https://www.test.com/whatever" to "https://test.com/w". In this case, if the SSL certificate was assigned to "www.test.com", you will get a red sign saying the certificate is valid but does not match the URL.

If that does not help, we would need more details on the SSL certificate, the exact SSL error you're getting, and examples of rewritten URL's.

Comment: I'm just re-writing the sub-domain and I will post the code in the main post. The thing is that I don't change anything, but making the link shorter without changing the domain or the https.